# Nginx Geoip module and a Simple Rotating banners Python script

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, bottle, geoip

We (friends and I) have a small dedicated server with nginx and the geoip module installed. (It's properly installed)
On that server we run a simple python script with UWSGI and bottle. 
The script rotates banners. 
(Our own banners for self-promotion)

We use this script to show banners of sites we own on other sites we own and rotate them so the user doesn't see always the same banner.

We have a problem with the geotargeting.

The following pastebin shows the python script.

http://pastebin.com/PqQ6TQeN

`PAISES = ['AR', 'MX', 'CL']` means the Country_code.
`TODOS` is the tag to show the banner to all countries.

The different lists are for different banner sizes.
The URL for the rotating banners is like this.

exampleip /api/300x250

This calls the template for the size of `300x250` so the user will see a random banner from our list for that size.

That works fine.
But the geotargeting isn't working.

In the code (pastebin link) you can see the 300x250 banners have only the "AR" code for Argentina, so only users from that country should see those ads.
However they keep being displayed for other IPs.

And after adding this:

```
print('>>>>> ',request.headers.keys())
pais = request.get_header('GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE')
print('=========== ' , pais, ' ==================')
```

(*Note: pais means country)

And running the UWSGI process via SSH It returns `None` for `GEOIP_CITY_COUNTRY_CODE`. 
That means it isn't passing the parameters right to the python script.

The Geoip module is properly installed but this script isn't working properly.

I need to get it fixed.

I'm sure it's not something complicated and I'm just writting something wrong in the code. Maybe I'm not passing the parameters right to uwsgi or python.